# How to set permissions for publishing new Wiki version on VSTS

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, wiki

We've published our Wiki pages in VSTS using 'code as Wiki' ([see explanation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/collaborate/wiki-select-unpublish-versions?view=vsts)). In general we only want to use the master branch for displaying these Wiki pages, but sometimes we want to add a new version using the *Publish new version* menu option (see screenshot).

[image]

However for some of my team members it isn't possible to publish a new version, because that menu option is not visible. I've searched to see if there are certain permissions controlling this menu option, or any preview feature that should be enabled, but couldn't find any clues on this.

Does anyone know how to get this *Publish new version* available to everyone? Thanks!

**Edit 1**
It was suggested by Rodrigo Werlang to check out *Wiki security*, however this option is not available for 'code as Wiki', see screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just see the [Prerequisites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/collaborate/publish-repo-to-wiki?view=vsts#prerequisites) to publish a Git repository to a wiki:

> You must have the permission **Create repository** to publish code as
>   wiki. By default, this permissions is set for members of the [Project
>   Administrators group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/security/set-git-tfvc-repository-permissions?view=vsts).
>
> Anyone who has permissions to contribute to the Git repository can add
>   or edit wiki pages. Anyone with access to the team project, including
>   [stakeholders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/security/get-started-stakeholder?view=vsts), can view the wiki.

And the description about [Stakeholder wiki access](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/vsts/collaborate/manage-readme-wiki-permissions?view=vsts#stakeholder-wiki-access):

> Stakeholders in a project can read wiki pages and view revisions,
>   **however they can't perform any edit operations**. For example,
>   stakeholders can't create, edit, reorder, or revert changes to pages.
>
> Note: **Users with [Stakeholder access](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/vsts/security/get-started-stakeholder?view=vsts) have read-only permissions to
>   wiki pages. These permissions can't be changed**.

So, in your scenario you can follow below steps to see the **Publish new version** option:

1. Change the user access level to **Basic** if it was Stakeholder
   before.
2. Add the user to [Project Administrators group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/security/set-git-tfvc-repository-permissions?view=vsts) or have
   **Manage permissions** set to **Allow** for Git repositories.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In your wiki, go to Wiki Security

[image]

Take a look at the security page and set contribute, contribute pull request, create branch, create tag, manage notes, read.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I've checked this, but it doesn't seem to be available for 'code as Wiki' setups, see also my edited question above.

Comment: In that case try to set the permissions on the repository that will be used in the 'code as Wiki'. Please let me know if that works to edit my answer.